# What are the series inductors used for in this filter?

Tags: filter, line

Regarding the below filter, are the series toroid inductors at the very right end of the filter used for CM or differential mode filtering?:

[image]

I think R and Cx are for differential filtering. And the CM choke in the middle and the Cy caps are for CM filtering.

But how about the series inductors at the very end of the filter lines L' and N'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inductors on the right are for differential mode filtering. They will also have some impact on common mode filtering but, given that their inductance will be much smaller than the common mode inductor and Cy will be small, not much.